# Data type definition on IA32 (x86) machine

Tags: c, x86

[image]

i thought short is 1? why did it increase by 8, from 16 to 24?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of data type [*alignment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

> Can someone explain to me why the offset is 0, 4, 8 16 and 24?

The first item is always going to be at the beginning of the structure (offset 0).

The `char` takes up one byte, so the next offset would be 1. However, the `double*` is 4-byte aligned (for performance), so it goes to the next 4-byte offset, 4. On x86 (32-bit) a pointer is 4 bytes, so the next offset is 8, where `i` goes.

> I know the byte size for double is 8 and int is 4, but i thought short is 1? why did it increase by 8, from 16 to 24?

Comment: You have no way to know how big the short is, because you can only tell by looking at the alignment of the field *after* it.  There is no field after the short.  The reason the offset of **short s** is 24, 8 larger than the offset of **double d**, is because the double is 8 bytes.